# Possible to use the ISE as the host for embedded Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm adding Powershell support to an app as an internal automation/scripting language. One of the things I want to do is have a runtime environment where I can enter commands, get output, etc. So I started looking at implementing my own PSHost.

Then I imagined my future. Over time, I'll implement a prompt/command/execute/response+log loop, possibly a configurable UI, maybe some amount of debugging like simple breakpoints...

Oh no! I'll be writing my own ISE!

So my question is: is it possible to use the ISE for the Powershell scripting in my app? Perhaps through remoting? Perhaps through embedding of certain ISE components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any way that ISE exposes its interface except as an end-user application.  I have written a host, however, and it's not as bad as it sounds.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out writing a basic ISE was only a few hours of work. Not so bad. :)